# PHP Syntax highlighting problem

Tags: syntax-highlighting, php-mode

I'm very new to GNU Emacs. I use GNU Emacs 28.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.33, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2022-05-31. Here is my ~/.emacs file.

```
(setq-default tab-width 4)

(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))

(custom-set-variables
'(package-selected-packages '(php-mode ligature))
'(tool-bar-mode nil))
(custom-set-faces
'(default ((t (:family "Fira Code" :foundry "CTDB" :slant normal :weight normal :height    128 :width normal)))))

(require 'ligature)

;; Enable the www ligature in every possible major mode
(ligature-set-ligatures t '("www"))

;; Enable ligatures in programming modes                                                           
(ligature-set-ligatures 'prog-mode '("www" "**" "***" "**/" "*>" "*/" "\\\\" "\\\\\\"    "{-" "::"
                                 ":::" ":=" "!!" "!=" "!==" "-}" "----" "-->" "->" "->>"
                                 "-<" "-<<" "-~" "#{" "#[" "##" "###" "####" "#(" "#?" "#_"
                                 "#_(" ".-" ".=" ".." "..<" "..." "?=" "??" ";;" "/*" "/**"
                                 "/=" "/==" "/>" "//" "///" "&&" "||" "||=" "|=" "|>" "^=" "$>"
                                 "++" "+++" "+>" "=:=" "==" "===" "==>" "=>" "=>>" "<="
                                 "=<<" "=/=" ">-" ">=" ">=>" ">>" ">>-" ">>=" ">>>" "<*"
                                 "<*>" "<|" "<|>" "<$" "<$>" "<!--" "<-" "<--" "<->" "<+"
                                 "<+>" "<=" "<==" "<=>" "<=<" "<>" "<<" "<<-" "<<=" "<<<"
                                 "<~" "<~~" "</" "</>" "~@" "~-" "~>" "~~" "~~>" "%%"))

(global-ligature-mode 't)

(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/catppuccin")
(load-theme 'catppuccin t)

(setq catppuccin-flavor 'macchiato) ;; 'frappe or 'latte, 'macchiato, or 'mocha
(catppuccin-reload)

;; This happens with this active or inactive
;; php-mode
;;(use-package php-mode
;;  :commands php-mode
;;  :mode "\\.php\\'")
```

There seems to be a problem with quotes and syntax highlighting. I did a few google searches but I couldn't find anything that would solve my problem, tried turning php-mode on and off. I don't know what my next step should be.

Reopening the file seems to temporary fix it.

[image]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: If you run `emacs -Q` and then load `php-mode.elc` manually via `M-x load-file` (i.e. without any of the rest of your config), do you see the same thing?

Comment: @phils I get "Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, php". I did M-x load-file RET /home/razvbir/.emacs.d/elpa/php-mode-20230212.731/php-mode.elc. After this failed, I've copied the file in the same directory as my php file and I get the same error message. I just type php-m and use tab to complete the file name, I know the file is there.

Comment: @Drew My question is: what am I doing wrong? I assume this is not a php-mode bug and that I've might not configured something properly.

Comment: @RăzvanBirișan Ah, there's more than one library for it to load in that directory.  Try this instead: `emacs -Q -L /home/razvbir/.emacs.d/elpa/php-mode-20230212.731 -l php-mode`

Comment: Sometimes font-lock turns silently stops working if it has encountered an error. You could try to run the font lock debugger https://github.com/Lindydancer/font-lock-studio to see if sees any problem. (If it finds a problem it will open up the elisp debugger.) If this happens, you can send your source file which caused the problem to the php mode maintainers.

Comment: @phils After running that command in the terminal, it still happens. Here's a [screenshot](https://mega.nz/file/435UDA4R#n7qDhq0TwkhXoKJi-qPySRZfE6f7VGgXYZg_IWgfYiU), the last lines are red.

Comment: Ok. Your link doesn't work for me, but I can't reproduce the original issue (I see no face colouring on the curly braces at all).  My only suggestion is to try updating `php-mode`.  If you come up with a recipe for triggering the issue from that `emacs -Q ...` starting point, add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but my reputation is too low to comment. I've had this issue for years just as OP described.

I can reproduce it with emacs -Q, then loading php-mode with

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/php-mode-20230423.1446/")
(package-initialize)
```

You can see the last two curly braces are highlighted red incorrectly.

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/24344)